# Set HSQL script newline format

Tags: persistence, newline, hsqldb

We have a HSQL .script file in source control. Some of our developers use Linux, some use Windows. Each time there is a commit we have to deal with conflicts (each line in file has one) due to platform specific newline characters in script.

Is there a way to specify newline format for the HSQL script file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot specify the end of line (eol) format for the HSQLDB script. HSQLDB can read the .script file regardless of the eol format used when the file was saved.

Source control system usually allow to specify the eol format to use for text files. For example, Subversion has a svn:eol-style property which can be set to "native" for all or individual files.